# Encryption and decryption results are not same in TEA

Tags: c++, algorithm, encryption

I have implemented [TEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm) in C++. Following is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned long y=24,z=32, sum=0, 
        delta=0x9e3779b9, n=16 ;
    int k[4] = { 0x28, 0xc0, 0x20, 0xd0 };
    unsigned long v[2] = {0,0};
    cout<<"original y is "<< y<<". original z is "<<z<<endl;
    while (n-->0) 
    { 
        sum += delta ;
        y += ((z<<4)+k[0]) ^ (z+sum) ^ ((z>>5)+k[1]) ;
        z += ((y<<4)+k[2]) ^ (y+sum) ^ ((y>>5)+k[3]) ;
    } 
    v[0]=y ; v[1]=z ;
    cout<<"encrypted y is "<< v[0]<<". encrypted z is "<<v[1]<<endl;
    n=16;
    y=v[0];
    z=v[1];         
    delta=0x9e3779b9 ;
    sum=delta<<5 ;
    /* start cycle */
    while (n-->0) 
    {
        z-= ((y<<4)+k[2]) ^ (y+sum) ^ ((y>>5)+k[3]) ;
        y-= ((z<<4)+k[0]) ^ (z+sum) ^ ((z>>5)+k[1]) ;
        sum-=delta ;
    }
        v[0]=y ; v[1]=z ;

    cout<<"decrypted y is "<< v[0]<<". decrypted z is "<<v[1]<<endl;    
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

But in the end, the results are not same i.e. the decrypted value is different than the original inputs (`y` and `z`).
Please point out the mistake which I am unable to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `n` to 16, while the example implementation [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm) runs the loop 32 times.

If I change `n` to 32 in your code, it works: [See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58ca74bc314dd826)

Comment: Not to be picky, but the other answer seems to offer a better understanding of *why* it doesn't work, and how to solve it in the general case :)

Answer (score 3):

```
sum = n * delta
```

You compute `sum` as `delta << 5` which corresponds to `delta * 32`. That works for the default value of `n = 32` but you reduced `n` to `16` without fixing the computation of `sum`. Replace `sum=delta<<5;` by `sum = delta * n`.

Also note that reducing the number of rounds weakens the resistance against cryptoanalysis.